# Unable to sign in to LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

I couldn't sign in to LinkedIn with my email address. I tried the forgot password link which asked for an email address and then asked to either send a verification code via SMS or voice call to a phone number which is not my phone number. Therefore I wouldn't receive the verification code and cannot get through. There is no way to send the verification code to my email as far as I know.

Comment: If the phone number is not yours, is it really your account?

Comment: @6' white male  It's really my account since I own the email address. But the email name is quite common and people mistakenly use this name a lot i.e. anurat@gmail.com

Comment: @6' white male By the way, why do you remove the part that I can't use LinkedIn help forum. Isn't a good question also explain how I try to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

> *There is no way to send the verification code to my email as far as I know.*

**There is.**

When you click on [Forgot password?](https://www.linkedin.com/) on sign-in page, it redirect to a new page where it asks for **Email or phone**:

[image]

Once you entered the associated email or phone number, it will redirect to new page with the following options:

[image]

Choose your prefer option and click on Submit.

Note here: you have to enter a phone number with country code with plus(+) sign (or whatever is in use). For example: +447373006, where +44 is country code.

[Password Reset Basics](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1167)
If you still have problems accessing your account, [here are some additional tips to check out](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/1501).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some reasons, My list only have the bottom two options.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the contact us page on LinkedIn.
Here it is.

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/ask/TS-RHA